# AZ IoT Hub Edge Device can't pull Image from ACR

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-acr

I have an individual IoT edge Module, simple python code, packaged in a Docker Container and placed in an ACR registry.

When installing the module on one of my Edge Devices, it return `Reported by Device = No`.

- I have provided ACR credentials to the config file.
  [image: ACR credentials]
- OPC publisher is running on the same edge
  [image]
- the VM behind the edge device is an on-prem VM behind firewalls, but IoT Hub and OPC communication is working
- I spin up a second Edge w/ a Cloud VM and try to set up my module there as well. And it worked for a Cloud VM.
  [image]

Now, did I forgot something, any ideas why this set-up is not working and the Edge Device can't pull the Image?
Does it may has something to do w/ firewall settings. As far as I understand the procedure, is that the IoT Hub setup is there to exactly clear these issues out.

thank you all

Comment: edgeAgent returns: `Unable to process module test-model add or update as the module identity could not be obtained`

Comment: I would check the network settings in the ACR. Possibly it is blocking access from your device. See if you can pull it with a docker pull from a command prompt of the host.